# How to set QgsPropertyCollection via an dict

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I've to set some layer properties from all loaded layers using QgsPropertyCollection, and I handle it with this code below(doesn't have the loop for all layers yet it's for the activelayer only):

```
pc = QgsPropertyCollection('qpc')
lyr_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
txt_format = QgsTextFormat()

layer = iface.activeLayer()

fz = QgsProperty()
fs = QgsProperty()
fc = QgsProperty()
fls = QgsProperty()
fws = QgsProperty()
mla = QgsProperty()
oxy = QgsProperty()
pri = QgsProperty()
lr = QgsProperty()
px = QgsProperty()
py = QgsProperty()
fz.setField("sizetxt")
fs.setField("styletxt")
fc.setField("casetxt")
fls.setField("letterspacing")
fws.setField("wordspacing")
mla.setField("justtxt")
oxy.setField("offset_txt")
pri.setField("priority")
lr.setField("rotation")
px.setField("offsetx")
py.setField("offsety")
pc.setProperty(0, fz)
pc.setProperty(21, fs)
pc.setProperty(27, fc)
pc.setProperty(28, fls)
pc.setProperty(29, fws)
pc.setProperty(31, '/')
pc.setProperty(32, 0.8)
pc.setProperty(33, mla)
pc.setProperty(77, 0)
pc.setProperty(78, oxy)
pc.setProperty(87, pri)
pc.setProperty(96, lr)
pc.setProperty(9, px)
pc.setProperty(10, py)

txt_format.setFont(QFont("Xerox Sans Serif Narrow"))
txt_format.setSizeUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderPoints)
txt_format.setColor(QColor(0,0,0))

lyr_settings.setFormat(txt_format)
lyr_settings.setDataDefinedProperties(pc)
lyr_settings.enabled = True
lyr_settings.fieldName = "legenda"
lyr_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(lyr_settings)

layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(lyr_settings)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

As you see it's huge :(( ! So, I've tried things to shorten this code unsuccessfully. The last one its the code below using dicts to pass the parameters to QgsPropertyCollection, but doesn't work.

```
pc = QgsPropertyCollection('qpc')
lyr_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
txt_format = QgsTextFormat()

sf = {'fz':"sizetxt", 'fs':"styletxt", 'fc':"casetxt", 'fls':"letterspacing", 'fws':"wordspacing", 'mla':"justtxt", 'oxy':"offset_txt", 'pri':"priority", 'lr':"rotation", 'px':"offsetx", 'py':"offsety"}
sp = {0:'fz', 21:'fs', 27:'fc', 28:'fls', 29:'fws', 31:'/', 32:0.8, 33:'mla', 77:0, 78:'oxy', 87:'pri', 96:'lr', 9:'px', 10:'py'}

for k, v in sf.items():
    k = QgsProperty()
    k.setField(str(v))

for k, v in sp.items():
    pc.setProperty(k, str(v))

txt_format.setFont(QFont("Xerox Sans Serif Narrow"))
txt_format.setSizeUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderPoints)
txt_format.setColor(QColor(0,0,0))

lyr_settings.setFormat(txt_format)
lyr_settings.setDataDefinedProperties(pc)
lyr_settings.enabled = True
lyr_settings.fieldName = "legend"
lyr_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(lyr_settings)

layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(lyr_settings)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

This code doesn't return any errors, but don't set the parameters like previous one. Anyone can help to find what is missing in the code?

Comment: I Think this `k = QgsProperty()` is a problem, since k is a string and not a variable. You are trying [To convert string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/to-convert-string-to-variable-name). Not sure how to fix it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [@BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/32958/bera)'s comment is correct in that you are trying to assign a variable to a string. If you want to go this path then you could look at the post: [convert dictionary entries into variables - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090672/convert-dictionary-entries-into-variables-python) and apply the accepted answer.

But if you want to shorten your code a bit more, you could just use a single dictionary containing the propertly value and field name. And when you iterate through this, assign the `QgsProperty()` and `QgsPropertyCollection()` in the same loop:

```
pc = QgsPropertyCollection('qpc')
lyr_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
txt_format = QgsTextFormat()
layer = iface.activeLayer()

sp = {0:'sizetxt', 
    21:'styletxt', 
    27:'casetxt', 
    28:'letterspacing', 
    29:'wordspacing', 
    33:'justtxt', 
    78:'offset_txt', 
    87:'priority', 
    96:'rotation', 
    9:'offsetx', 
    10:'offsety'}

for k, v in sp.items():
    x = QgsProperty()
    x.setField(v)
    pc.setProperty(k, x)

txt_format.setFont(QFont("Xerox Sans Serif Narrow"))
txt_format.setSizeUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderPoints)
txt_format.setColor(QColor(0,0,0))

lyr_settings.setFormat(txt_format)
lyr_settings.setDataDefinedProperties(pc)
lyr_settings.enabled = True
lyr_settings.fieldName = "legend"
lyr_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(lyr_settings)

layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(lyr_settings)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: @FranciscoCamello - Most welcome, glad it helped :)